# Solr Learning to Rank Plugin Setup?

Tags: java, plugins, solr, ant, compiler-errors

I am trying to setup the Learning to Rank Plugin for Solr located here:
https://github.com/bloomberg/lucene-solr/tree/master-ltr-plugin-release/solr/contrib/ltr

I've got the Java JDK as well as Apache Ant all set up as that is what the plugin uses to compile and I have verified that both of those are setup properly as their commands are recognized. Note that I am running on Windows 7.

I follow the instructions listed below in that link, but cannot even get passed the first step. I execute the commands to compile "ant dist" and "ant server" and I just get a NullPointerException. I've tried compiling at the root directory, the "solr" directory, as well as just the "ltr" directory, but I get the same error each time.

I'm not sure if its an issue with the plugin being outdated or something I'm missing with my setup as there does not seem to be much info on issues with these particular components. Hoping I can find somebody who might know what's going wrong here. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Oh and here is the error message I get when trying to compile:

```
C:\Users\aan7771\Desktop\SOLR-ML-PLUGIN\lucene-solr-master-ltr-plugin-release\so
lr>ant dist
Buildfile: C:\Users\aan7771\Desktop\SOLR-ML-PLUGIN\lucene-solr-master-ltr-plugin
-release\solr\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\aan7771\Desktop\SOLR-ML-PLUGIN\lucene-solr-master-ltr-plugin-release\so
lr\build.xml:39: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\aan7771\Desktop\SOLR-ML-PLUGIN\lucene-solr-master-ltr-plugin-release\so
lr\common-build.xml:54: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\aan7771\Desktop\SOLR-ML-PLUGIN\lucene-solr-master-ltr-plugin-release\lu
cene\module-build.xml:27: The following error occurred while executing this line
:
C:\Users\aan7771\Desktop\SOLR-ML-PLUGIN\lucene-solr-master-ltr-plugin-release\lu
cene\common-build.xml:542: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5004)
        at java.util.stream.Stream.of(Stream.java:1000)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:
267)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:
193)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators
.java:948)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)

        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.ja
va:471)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)

        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipelin
e.java:260)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438
)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ChainedMapper.lambda$mapFileName$1(ChainedM
apper.java:36)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$1ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:80)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.j
ava:1382)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)

        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.ja
va:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java
:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)

        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:484)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ChainedMapper.mapFileName(ChainedMapper.jav
a:35)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.CompositeMapper.lambda$mapFileName$0(Compos
iteMapper.java:32)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:
193)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:
175)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.j
ava:1382)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)

        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.ja
va:471)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)

        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipelin
e.java:260)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438
)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.CompositeMapper.mapFileName(CompositeMapper
.java:33)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.PathConvert.execute(PathConvert.java:36
3)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:346)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:448)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:
172)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.ja
va:221)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:165)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:346)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:448)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:
172)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.ja
va:221)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:165)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:346)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:448)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:
172)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.ja
va:221)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:165)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:346)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:448)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:
183)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.jav
a:93)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:824)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:228)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:283)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)

Total time: 0 seconds

C:\Users\aan7771\Desktop\SOLR-ML-PLUGIN\lucene-solr-master-ltr-plugin-release\so
lr>
```

Comment: The [LTR plugin is currently bundled with Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/learning-to-rank.html). Any reason you can't use that?

Comment: That is what I'm using, do I not follow the instructions in the link in my post in that case..?

Comment: In that case you should find a pre-compiled version under `/dist/solr-ltr-7.2.1.jar`.

Comment: I'm not seeing a /dist folder either, is that created after compiling? Because I get the same error when just trying to compile Solr itself as well.

Comment: No need to compile anything, it's bundled with the binary distribution of Solr.

Comment: Oh I was downloading the source code so it did not include the .jars, but the binary version did. It seems to work with the latest version of Solr so thank you! Although, we are using 6.0.0 and it does not seem to work with that.. I suppose we will have to look into upgrading but that is a whole separate issue.